# How to set focus on the WPF DataGrid or its first row?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have WPF `DataGrid` placed on the `Window`. I have a button which performs some business logic and populates the grid.

**I want to set focus on the `DataGrid` (preferably first row in the DataGrid) when i `TAB` from the button.** I have set the `TabIndex` but somehow the focus does not come on the DataGrid.

The relevant part of the form's XAML is here:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,10,10,10">
    <Button Content="Search"
                Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-25,0,0"
                Name="btnSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" **TabIndex="1300"** Click="btnSearch_Click" Keyboard.KeyDown="btnSearch_PreviewKeyDown" LostFocus="btnSearch_LostFocus"/>
</StackPanel>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,160,10,10" Name="dataGridOrganisations" **TabIndex="1400"**
          BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Focusable="True"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" GridLinesVisibility="None"
           ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="dataGridOrganisations_SelectionChanged" Keyboard.PreviewKeyDown="dataGridOrganisations_PreviewKeyDown"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shortname" Width="100" Binding="{Binding ShortName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Internal Code" Width="100" Binding="{Binding LocalID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I added following code on Button's `LostFocus` event, it highlights the first row. But when I use 'down' arrow key to select next row in the grid; instead of going to next row it first sets focus on the 'Search' button and next time goes to second row!

```
if (this.dataGridOrganisations != null && this.dataGridOrganisations.HasItems)
{
    this.dataGridOrganisations.Focus();
    if (dataGridOrganisations.Items != null && dataGridOrganisations.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        DataGridRow firstRow = this.dataGridOrganisations.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGridOrganisations.Items[0]) as DataGridRow;
        if (firstRow != null)
        {
            firstRow.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

How to set focus on the DataGrid (or its first row)? Why `TabIndex` does not work here?

Comment: Please go through comments on H.B.'s answer. The problem is solved after H.B. pointed that TabIndex was not required. Moving DataGrid inside the StackPanel of the Button control solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not even need a tab-index if there are no focusable controls between the `Button` and `DataGrid` in the control hierarchy. You have quite a few handlers and everything seems a bit convoluted to me. I cannot spot anything in that code (maybe someone else can of course), my suggestion would be that you try to simplify your code until it works again as it should by default. e.g. this code's tabbing should work:

```
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Lorem Ipsum"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </StackPanel>
```

Also, why the large tab-index delta? If you were to use 1301 & 1302 there could not be any value between so it should automatically be safer code.

Comment: It was typo; I have added code on button's LostFocus event, not on DataGrid's. I have corrected the question now.

Comment: @CSharpLearner: Well, you should not need that handler anyway.

Comment: There is no control between Button and DataGrid.  But the Button is part of the StackPanel and DataGrid is out of the StackPanel. By the way, I removed all Tab-Indexes as you mentioned. Tabbing works fine but it always skips the DataGrid and focus is set on the next control (next to DataGrid) from the Button.

Comment: @CSharpLearner: The StackPanel does not matter as it is no input-element. (You can wrap the Button in my example code in one, it will still work.) Just try to further simplify your code to pin down the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answers. It helped me. I removed tab indexes and moved `DataGrid` inside the `StackPanel` and it solved my problem! Tabbing inside the `DataGrid` moves control from one cell to another which I want to stop now but it's not part of this question.

Comment: @CSharpLearner: `Ctrl+Tab` tabs out of the DataGrid, i would not recommend changing the function of the normal Tab press. (There are already questions covering this if you really must do that by the way).

Answer (score 2):

Add following code in datagrid of xaml

```
SelectedIndex="0" Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded"
```

add below code in .cs file

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        dataGrid.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGrid1.SelectedIndex = 0;

DataGrid1.Focus();
```

You can put any integer you want to the selectedindex.