# WPF DataGrid programmatically go to First Row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

This is my code

Version 1

```
public void scrollIntoGrid(DataGrid grid)
        {
            object item = grid.Items[0];
            grid.SelectedItem = item;
            grid.ScrollIntoView(item);
            grid.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First));
            grid.SelectedIndex = 0;
            //DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem);         
            //row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Left));
            //row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Up));
        }
```

Version 2

```
public void scrollIntoGrid(DataGrid grid)
        {
            object item = grid.Items[0];
            grid.SelectedItem = item;
            grid.ScrollIntoView(item);
            //grid.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First));
            //grid.SelectedIndex = 0;
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem);
            row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First));
            //row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Up));
        }
```

and all iterations go to second row in grid and not the first.
[image]

Comment: looks like a duplicate question. Did you see this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565337/how-to-set-focus-on-the-wpf-datagrid-or-its-first-row

Comment: That doesn't answer my particular issue, Focus goes to the DataGrid, but the row selected is the second and not the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coming back to this after some time, the solution I found working is on KeyUp event in text box.

```
if (e.Key == Key.Down)
 {
  object item = dgProductSaleInvSm.Items[0];
  dgProductSaleInvSm.SelectedItem = item;
  dgProductSaleInvSm.ScrollIntoView(item);
  DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dgProductSaleInvSm.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
 row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code does work for me. On Button-Click it selects the first Row. If that is that what you mean with `go to first row`.

If the your interpretation of the first row is the header row then this would not work.
Your scroolIntoGrid function could look like this:

```
  public void scrollIntoGrid(DataGrid grid)
    {

        if(grid != null && grid.HasItems)
        {
            grid.SelectedIndex = 0;
            grid.Focus();
        }
       
    }
```

Full code here:

Code behind file:

```
 public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    

}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var listOfPersons = new List<Person> { { 
                new Person { Firstname="Hello",Lastname="World"} },
            new Person {Firstname="World",Lastname="Hello"} };
        mygrid.DataContext = listOfPersons;
        
        
    }


    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        scrollIntoGrid(this.mygrid);
    }



    public void scrollIntoGrid(DataGrid grid)
    {

        if(grid != null && grid.HasItems)
        {
            grid.SelectedIndex = 0;
            grid.Focus();
        }
       
    }

  
}
```

}

XAML File:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,10,10,10">
        <Button Content="Search"
            Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Margin="20,10,10,10"
            Name="btnSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" TabIndex="1300" Click="btnSearch_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="mygrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,160,10,10" 
              BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Focusable="True"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" GridLinesVisibility="None"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" 
             >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shortname" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Firstname}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Internal Code" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Lastname}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

---

Based on your comment that you actually want to jump from a textbox on arrow down key the following changes did the trick for me.

Added a XAML TextBox with an `PreviewKeyDown` event

```
<TextBox x:Name="searchBox" PreviewKeyDown="searchBox_KeyDown"></TextBox>
```

And in code behind:

```
  private void searchBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down) // The Arrow-Down key
        {
            scrollIntoGrid(mygrid);
            e.Handled = true;
            Keyboard.Focus(mygrid);
        }
    }
```

ScrollIntoGrid stayed the same as described above.

Comment: Still not doesn't work for me, my use case is, use search in text box, then presses Down Arrow on Keyboard, focus should then shift to the grid and select the first row. My original code works but goes to the second row.

Comment: updated the answer based on your comment.